Address Mismatch in Ethereum Signature Verification with Safe via WalletConnect
I'm facing an issue with Ethereum signature verification. When I sign a message using Safe through WalletConnect, the verified address does not match the signed wallet address. This problem occurs only when using Safe, and not with MetaMask or other wallets through WalletConnect.
Here's the relevant code:
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import Web3Token from 'web3-token';

interface AuthenticationStatus {
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  message?: string;
  address?: string;
  token?: string;
}

class AuthService {
  signer: ethers.Signer;

  constructor(signer: ethers.Signer) {
    this.signer = signer;
  }

  async isUserAuthenticated(): Promise<AuthenticationStatus> {
    try {
      if (!this.signer) {
        console.log('Signer not provided');
        return { isAuthenticated: false, message: 'Signer not provided' };
      }
  
      const userAddress = await this.signer.getAddress();
      console.log('User address:', userAddress);
  
      const cookieName = `auth_${userAddress.toLowerCase()}`;
      const authToken = Cookies.get(cookieName);
      console.log('Auth token:', authToken);
  
      if (!authToken) {
        console.log('Auth token not found');
        return { isAuthenticated: false, message: 'Auth token not found' };
      }
  
      const { address, body } = Web3Token.verify(authToken);
      console.log('Verified address:', address);
      console.log('body:', body);

      const decodedBody = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(authToken, 'base64').toString('utf-8'));

      const message = decodedBody.body;
      const signature = decodedBody.signature;

      console.log('decodedBody:', decodedBody);
      console.log('Message:', message);
      console.log('Signature:', signature);

      if (!message || !signature) {
        console.log('Message or signature not found in the token body');
        return { isAuthenticated: false, message: 'Invalid token structure' };
      }

      const recoveredAddress = ethers.utils.verifyMessage(message, signature);
      console.log('Recovered Address:', recoveredAddress);
  
      if (address.toLowerCase() !== userAddress.toLowerCase() || recoveredAddress.toLowerCase() !== userAddress.toLowerCase()) {
        Cookies.remove(cookieName);
        console.log('Invalid token or signature');
        return { isAuthenticated: false, message: 'Invalid token or signature' };
      }
  
      return { isAuthenticated: true, address: address.toLowerCase(), token: authToken };
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error in isUserAuthenticated:', error);
      return { isAuthenticated: false };
    }
  }
  
  async authenticate(): Promise<boolean> {
    try {
      if (!this.signer) {
        throw Error('No signer provided');
      }
  
      const address = await this.signer.getAddress();
      console.log('Address:', address);
  
      const cookieName = `auth_${address.toLowerCase()}`;
      const token = await Web3Token.sign(async (msg: string) => await this.signer!.signMessage(msg), {
        statement: 'Please sign this message to authenticate.',
        expires_in: '30d',
      });
  
      console.log('Generated token:', token);
      Cookies.set(cookieName, token, { expires: 30 });
      console.log('Cookie set:', cookieName);
  
      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error obtaining token:', error);
      return false;
    }
  }
}

Here are the packages I'm using:
"next": "14.1.3",
"@web3modal/ethers5": "^4.1.11"
"ethers": "^5.7.2"
"web3-token": "^1.0.6"

Example Console Output from MetaMask (Match):
Address: 0x2E8b567344cACC935f539fce9B7fCC342e942298
Generated token: eyJzaWduYXR1cmUiOiIweGVjNDMwMjdmYzMwYzVhMTM2NzMyYWU4YTk3MWI1NDYyYjk5MWQ3NDNkMDlkMjFkNmE5ZDUxOTk1NTJlNjA1MmI2YTE5NDZjNmE5OTA0Y2QxYTA5ZmU3YWMyNWZkMWQyYzkwNTAxMDUzYjY2ZTFhN2YzMjE2YzJkOWQyMjMzYjE1MWMiLCJib2R5IjoiUGxlYXNlIHNpZ24gdGhpcyBtZXNzYWdlIHRvIGF1dGhlbnRpY2F0ZS5cblxuVVJJOiBodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjMwMDEvYXBwL2Vhcm4/cG9vbFR5cGU9TEFVTkNIJnRva2VuPUFMTCZ0PTE2XG5XZWIzIFRva2VuIFZlcnNpb246IDJcbklzc3VlZCBBdDogMjAyNC0wNy0xNVQxNjowOTo1MC40OThaXG5FeHBpcmF0aW9uIFRpbWU6IDIwMjQtMDgtMTRUMTY6MDk6NTAuNDk4WiJ9
Cookie set: auth_0x2e8b567344cacc935f539fce9b7fcc342e942298
User address: 0x2E8b567344cACC935f539fce9B7fCC342e942298
Auth token: eyJzaWduYXR1cmUiOiIweGVjNDMwMjdmYzMwYzVhMTM2NzMyYWU4YTk3MWI1NDYyYjk5MWQ3NDNkMDlkMjFkNmE5ZDUxOTk1NTJlNjA1MmI2YTE5NDZjNmE5OTA0Y2QxYTA5ZmU3YWMyNWZkMWQyYzkwNTAxMDUzYjY2ZTFhN2YzMjE2YzJkOWQyMjMzYjE1MWMiLCJib2R5IjoiUGxlYXNlIHNpZ24gdGhpcyBtZXNzYWdlIHRvIGF1dGhlbnRpY2F0ZS5cblxuVVJJOiBodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjMwMDEvYXBwL2Vhcm4/cG9vbFR5cGU9TEFVTkNIJnRva2VuPUFMTCZ0PTE2XG5XZWIzIFRva2VuIFZlcnNpb246IDJcbklzc3VlZCBBdDogMjAyNC0wNy0xNVQxNjowOTo1MC40OThaXG5FeHBpcmF0aW9uIFRpbWU6IDIwMjQtMDgtMTRUMTY6MDk6NTAuNDk4WiJ9
Verified address: 0x2e8b567344cacc935f539fce9b7fcc342e942298
body: { "uri": "http://localhost:3001/app/earn?poolType=LAUNCH&token=ALL&t=16", "web3-token-version": "2", "issued-at": "2024-07-15T16:09:50.498Z", "expiration-time": "2024-08-14T16:09:50.498Z", "statement": "Please sign this message to authenticate." }
decodedBody: { "signature": "0xec43027fc30c5a136732ae8a971b5462b991d743d09d21d6a9d5199552e6052b6a1946c6a9904cd1a09fe7ac25fd1d2c90501053b66e1a7f3216c2d9d2233b151c", "body": "Please sign this message to authenticate.\n\nURI: http://localhost:3001/app/earn?poolType=LAUNCH&token=ALL&t=16\nWeb3 Token Version: 2\nIssued At: 2024-07-15T16:09:50.498Z\nExpiration Time: 2024-08-14T16:09:50.498Z" }
Message: Please sign this message to authenticate. URI: http://localhost:3001/app/earn?poolType=LAUNCH&token=ALL&t=16 Web3 Token Version: 2 Issued At: 2024-07-15T16:09:50.498Z Expiration Time: 2024-08-14T16:09:50.498Z
Signature: 0xec43027fc30c5a136732ae8a971b5462b991d743d09d21d6a9d5199552e6052b6a1946c6a9904cd1a09fe7ac25fd1d2c90501053b66e1a7f3216c2d9d2233b151c
Recovered Address: 0x2E8b567344cACC935f539fce9B7fCC342e942298

Example console output from Safe (Mismatch):
Address: 0x5Fc1EB9e2877c50CA6e264E73615254a69894698
Generated token: eyJzaWduYXR1cmUiOiIweDZkOGM5YmZmZTJmOTljMmZjODE5ODc0NTg0NzAxZGZlNjExZGI0ZGUxZTlkNGMwYjliOTM0ZmQ0YmU5ODljMzk1ZTkyN2MwMzY3MDk1MDYyZWYxZjY5ZTdjYjZhNTNhZDE3YjIzNjc3ZGYzMzRlODMzNzQ2MTlhZDdlYWMwYmY0MWMiLCJib2R5IjoiUGxlYXNlIHNpZ24gdGhpcyBtZXNzYWdlIHRvIGF1dGhlbnRpY2F0ZS5cblxuVVJJOiBodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjMwMDEvYXBwL2Vhcm4/cG9vbFR5cGU9TEFVTkNIJnRva2VuPUFMTCZ0PTE2XG5XZWIzIFRva2VuIFZlcnNpb246IDJcbklzc3VlZCBBdDogMjAyNC0wNy0xNVQxNjoxMzo1NC4yODBaXG5FeHBpcmF0aW9uIFRpbWU6IDIwMjQtMDgtMTRUMTY6MTM6NTQuMjgwWiJ9
Cookie set: auth_0x5fc1eb9e2877c50ca6e264e73615254a69894698
User address: 0x5Fc1EB9e2877c50CA6e264E73615254a69894698
Auth token: eyJzaWduYXR1cmUiOiIweDZkOGM5YmZmZTJmOTljMmZjODE5ODc0NTg0NzAxZGZlNjExZGI0ZGUxZTlkNGMwYjliOTM0ZmQ0YmU5ODljMzk1ZTkyN2MwMzY3MDk1MDYyZWYxZjY5ZTdjYjZhNTNhZDE3YjIzNjc3ZGYzMzRlODMzNzQ2MTlhZDdlYWMwYmY0MWMiLCJib2R5IjoiUGxlYXNlIHNpZ24gdGhpcyBtZXNzYWdlIHRvIGF1dGhlbnRpY2F0ZS5cblxuVVJJOiBodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjMwMDEvYXBwL2Vhcm4/cG9vbFR5cGU9TEFVTkNIJnRva2VuPUFMTCZ0PTE2XG5XZWIzIFRva2VuIFZlcnNpb246IDJcbklzc3VlZCBBdDogMjAyNC0wNy0xNVQxNjoxMzo1NC4yODBaXG5FeHBpcmF0aW9uIFRpbWU6IDIwMjQtMDgtMTRUMTY6MTM6NTQuMjgwWiJ9
Verified address: 0xf115f41275de296969d3e89c50f25d20d69eb5b5
body: { "uri": "http://localhost:3001/app/earn?poolType=LAUNCH&token=ALL&t=16", "web3-token-version": "2", "issued-at": "2024-07-15T16:13:54.280Z", "expiration-time": "2024-08-14T16:13:54.280Z", "statement": "Please sign this message to authenticate." }
decodedBody: { "signature": "0x6d8c9bffe2f99c2fc819874584701dfe611db4de1e9d4c0b9b934fd4be989c395e927c0367095062ef1f69e7cb6a53ad17b23677df334e83374619ad7eac0bf41c", "body": "Please sign this message to authenticate.\n\nURI: http://localhost:3001/app/earn?poolType=LAUNCH&token=ALL&t=16\nWeb3 Token Version: 2\nIssued At: 2024-07-15T16:13:54.280Z\nExpiration Time: 2024-08-14T16:13:54.280Z" }
Message: Please sign this message to authenticate. URI: http://localhost:3001/app/earn?poolType=LAUNCH&token=ALL&t=16 Web3 Token Version: 2 Issued At: 2024-07-15T16:13:54.280Z Expiration Time: 2024-08-14T16:13:54.280Z
Signature: 0x6d8c9bffe2f99c2fc819874584701dfe611db4de1e9d4c0b9b934fd4be989c395e927c0367095062ef1f69e7cb6a53ad17b23677df334e83374619ad7eac0bf41c
Recovered Address: 0xf115f41275de296969D3E89C50F25d20D69eb5b5

I tried verifying the authToken using Web3Token.verify and decoding the base64 body to extract the message and signature. Then, I used ethers.utils.verifyMessage to recover the address.
I expected the recovered address to match the signed wallet address. This works correctly with MetaMask, but with Safe via WalletConnect, the recovered & verified address does not match.

Has anyone encountered this issue or have any insights on how to resolve it?
Any guidance on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!

To resolve this, I removed the Web3Token.verify call and manually decoded the base64 body to extract the message and signature. Then, I used a custom verifySignature function to handle both standard signature verification and EIP-1271 signature verification, which is necessary for Safe wallets.
Here’s the updated isUserAuthenticated function and the verifySignature function I used:
async isUserAuthenticated(): Promise<AuthenticationStatus> {
    try {
        if (!this.signer) {
            return { isAuthenticated: false, message: 'Signer not provided' };
        }

        const userAddress = await this.signer.getAddress();
        const cookieName = `auth_${userAddress.toLowerCase()}`;
        const authToken = Cookies.get(cookieName);

        if (!authToken) {
            return { isAuthenticated: false, message: 'Auth token not found' };
        }

        const decodedBody = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(authToken, 'base64').toString('utf-8'));

        const message = decodedBody.body;
        const signature = decodedBody.signature;
        if (!message || !signature) {
            console.error('Message or signature not found in the token body');
            return { isAuthenticated: false, message: 'Invalid token structure' };
        }

        const isValid = await this.verifySignature(userAddress, message, signature);
        if (!isValid) {
            Cookies.remove(cookieName);
            return { isAuthenticated: false, message: 'Invalid token or signature' };
        }

        return { isAuthenticated: true, address: userAddress.toLowerCase(), token: authToken };
    } catch (error) {
        return { isAuthenticated: false };
    }
}

async verifySignature(address: string, message: string, signature: string): Promise<boolean> {
    // First, try standard signature verification
    try {
        const recoveredAddress = ethers.utils.verifyMessage(message, signature);
        if (recoveredAddress.toLowerCase() === address.toLowerCase()) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Standard signature verification error: ', error);
    }

    // If standard verification fails, try EIP-1271 verification
    try {
        const SafeInterface = new ethers.utils.Interface([
            'function isValidSignature(bytes32 _hash, bytes memory _signature) public view returns (bytes4)'
        ]);

        const safeContract = new ethers.Contract(address, SafeInterface, this.signer?.provider);
        const messageHash = ethers.utils.hashMessage(message);
        const isValidSignature = await safeContract.isValidSignature(messageHash, signature);

        return isValidSignature === '0x1626ba7e'; // EIP-1271 magic value
    } catch (error) {
        return false;
    }
}

In this approach, verifySignature first attempts standard message verification using ethers.utils.verifyMessage. If that fails, it then attempts EIP-1271 verification by calling isValidSignature on the Safe contract, which is essential for Safe wallets.
This solution ensures that both standard wallets (like MetaMask) and Safe wallets via WalletConnect are handled appropriately, resolving the mismatch issue.
